# Алгоритм кратчайшего пути(матрица смежности)

Tags: графы, алгоритм, c++

Задано N городов-вершин графов. Ребра графа-время на дорогу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по какому алгоритму можно вычислить минимальный путь(не минимальное расстояние, а именно минимальный путь). т.е. программа должна указать маршрут, по которому следует двигаться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, [Алгоритм Дейкстры](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B).

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой "Волновой алгоритм".  Работает для 4 и 8 направлений.
Реализаций огромное количество для С++.

Есть еще много алгоритмов, но реализации как правило выполнены не качественно обычными студентами.

Похожий вопрос:

1. [Первый](http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=166742)
2. [подробное описание алгоритма A*(а-звезда)](http://scr1pter.blogspot.ru/2011/05/blog-post_13.html).
3. Реализации нескольких [алгоритмов](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/). Самый большой выбор, но в тоже время мало описания и на сколько помню есть ошибки.